# How can I prefer one wifi network over another?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

From my home I have access to my home wifi network as well as a public network that is deployed throughout the city.  The public network has a lower signal strength and is unprotected.  However, my computer sometimes connects to that network instead of my home network.  Other than "forgetting" the public network, is there a way to tell NetworkManager to prefer my home network over other networks?

Comment: For Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/165679/how-to-manage-available-wireless-network-priority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You could choose the public city wifi setting from networkmanager and disable automatic connection:

Manage Connections -> Wireless -> Choose Access Point(City's Wifi in this case) -> Uncheck "Connect Automatically"